# Publishing an App to the google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I am getting ready to push my first android app to the market but there are a two questions I have before I sign up as a developer.

I did some reading and found this link on alpha/beta testing:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

1) Can you have an app in alpha/beta testing without having one in production? So I want to first publish my application to a few people just to make sure the layouts and everything works out good.

2) I know some apps are phone only or tablet only, is this done in the play store or in the app (such as the AndroidManifest)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [developer-centric app store questions are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes you don't need to have a production apk in the app, you can upload your apk in alpha for some testing then you can select the apk and move it to beta and then make it public on market. It also supports Staged rollouts.

Follow this guide to manage your app testing groups. ([Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en))

2) No this can't be done in Google play developer console. This has to be done in the manifest using this:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

more information here. ([support-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)) and here ([uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features))

You can also add more required features. And when you upload the apk to google play , you can check how many devices are valid for your app, or excluded. Then only devices that meat your requirements can see the application in the store.

[image]

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you can publish an app in alpha or beta testing without publishing to full production.